# When should I find the min and max for a BoundingBox attached to a Model

Tags: c++, performance, graphics, directx

I'm working on implementing a ModelClass for any 3D model in my DirectX 11/12 pipeline.

My specific problem lies within calculating the min and max for the BoundingBox structure I wish to use as a member of the ModelClass.

I have two approaches to calculating them.

**Approach 1.**
When each vertex is being read from file, store a current minx,y,z and maxx,y,z and check each vertex as it is loaded in against the current min/max x,y,z.

**Approach 2.**
After all the vertices have been loaded, sort them by x, then y, then z, finding the lowest and highest value at each point.

Which Approach would you recommend and why?

Comment: Approach 1 looks simpler and more efficient to me as there is no sorting whatsoever involved. Why don't you try? How many vertexes do you have?

Comment: **Approach 3**: Compute the bounding volumes (box and sphere) offline and store them in a file along with compact forms of your geometry and materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Approach 1

Time complexity is in O(n) and memory complexity is O(1).

It is simple to implement.

## Approach 2

Time complexity is O(nLogn) memory complexity is potentially at least linear (if you make a copy of the arrays or if you use merge sort) or O(1) if you use an in place sorting algorithm like quicksort.

This has to be done 3 times one for each dimension.

All in all Approach 1 is best in all scenarios I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting generally is not a cheap operation especially as your models are getting larger. Therefore it to me like Approach 1 is more efficient but if unsure I suggest measuring it see which one takes longer.

If you are using a library like Asspimp I believe the library takes care of bounding boxes but this might not be an option if you create the pipeline as a learning opportunity.